# Limit Proof for Function Growth

Tags: limits, proof-writing

Show that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}, a \in \mathbb{R^+}$,

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{(\ln x)^n}{x^a} = 0$$

**Attempt:**
I tried splitting what was inside the limit into $\frac{(\ln x)}{x^a} \times (\ln x)^{n-1}$.
And because both limits exist (Is this correct and can I say this?), I can do the following:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{(\ln x)}{x^a} \times \lim_{x\to \infty} (\ln x)^{n-1} = 0$$

Then the problem becomes much simpler.

Can anyone suggest a solution? I'm not sure if this is the correct approach.

Note: We can use L'Hospital's rule.

Comment: This doesn' t look right for $a=0$ or $a<0$

Comment: @ThomasL Yes, you are correct. I have made $a$ to be any positive real.

Comment: And $\ln{n-1}x\to\infty$ if $n>1$.

Comment: But does $\lim_{x\to\infty} (\ln x)^{n-1}$ exist though?

Comment: @peterwhy oh right, it doesn't because lim approaches infinity which does not exist. How do you suppose I solve this then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\dfrac{(\ln x)^n}{x^a}$ is in $\dfrac\infty\infty$ form, directly applying L'Hôpital's rule gives

$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(\ln x)^n}{x^a} &= \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{n(\ln x)^{n-1}\frac 1x}{ax^{a-1}}\\
&= \lim_{x\to\infty}  \frac{n(\ln x)^{n-1}}{ax^{a}}\\
&= \frac na \lim_{x\to\infty}  \frac{(\ln x)^{n-1}}{x^{a}}\\
&\vdots\\
&= \frac {n!}{a^n} \lim_{x\to\infty}  \frac{(\ln x)^{0}}{x^{a}}\\
&= \frac {n!}{a^n} \lim_{x\to\infty}  \frac{1}{x^{a}}\\
\end{align*}$$

With a base case that when $n=0$, the limit is $0$, this proves the limit.

Answer (score 2):

You can substitute $t=\ln x$ and you get

$$\lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{t^n}{e^{at}} $$
Now you can use L'Hospital n times to get 0 (important here is a>0).

Comment: After using L'Hopital's Rule once, I get: $\frac{n}{a} \lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{t^{n-1}}{e^{at}}$. I don't see how after doing it $n$ times, we get 0.

Comment: $\lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{t^n}{e^{at}} $ = $\lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{nt^{n-1}}{ae^{at}} $ = ... = $\lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{n!}{a^ne^{at}} $ = 0

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

You can prove the more general result $$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\ln^bx}{x^a}=0\quad(a,b\in\mathbf R^+)$$
showing its logarithm tends to $-\infty$. Indeed,we have
$$\ln\biggl(\frac{\ln^bx}{x^a}\biggr)=b\ln(\ln x)-a\ln x=\ln x\,\biggl(b\frac{\ln(\ln x)}{\ln x}-a\biggr)$$
and set $t=\ln x$ in the second factor.